# install activinspire on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line

How do I install activinspire on ubuntu 18.04?
There is one article on the web but it is in Italian. Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there are two problems: the kernel 4.15 is not managed (so exit ubuntu 16.04.5 and 18.04) and it must be a 32-bit system or add 32-bit packages on an architecture 64 bits.

So it seems that this package will not work on a 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04 system.

And it seems there is no prospect of it being developed further.

> We currently have no other updates regarding ActivInspire support for
>   Ubuntu 18.04.
>
> Regards, Adam Promethean Technical Support

There is a possible suggested solution:

- install on VirtualBox: See reference [here](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu/).

> A virtual machine is a computer in a computer. Basically, you have a
>   program (virtualbox) that will "simulate a new computer" in which you
>   have to install ubuntu 16.04 32 bits and then the promethean drivers
>   (easy since it's 32 bits), but it is necessary that the ordi (sic) [computer] be able
>   to assume a virtual machine.

Source: https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2032702
(Translate using Google or similar)

Answer (score 0):

https://support.prometheanworld.com/article/1758

This appears to have changed? I currently run activinspire on my 16.04 machine but this looks promising for potential upgrades over the next LTS cycle.